# Android retrofit expected BEING_OBJECT but was string at line 1 column 1

Tags: java, php, android, api

I'm having trouble while i was creating an Android App that have to LogIn or Register. I'm using Retrofit that make a request to a php file in my server. Below I put my code, i searched everywhere for a solution but  I didn't found nothing. What I'm tryng to do is registration for now, I'm tryng to insert data in my sql database. Sorry for my bad english

Api Client

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://tommytest22.000webhostapp.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Api Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/save.php")
    Call<Utente> salvaUtente(
          //  @Field("id_utente") int id_utente,
            @Field("username") String username,
            @Field("password") String password
    );

}
```

User Class

```
public class Utente {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("id_utente") private int id_utente;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("username") private String username;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("password") private String password;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("success") private Boolean success;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("messaggio") private String messaggio;
}
```

Registration Method activate by click on button

```
private boolean registraUtente(final String username,final String password){
    progressDialog.show();
    apiInterface= ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<Utente> call= apiInterface.salvaUtente(username,password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Utente>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Utente> call, @NonNull Response<Utente> response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                Boolean success = response.body().getSuccess();
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessaggio(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessaggio(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Utente> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return true;
    }
```

connect.php

```
<?php   
    $conn=mysqli_connect(PARAMETERS);
    
    if($conn){
    
    }else{
        echo "not connected";
    }
?>
```

save.php:

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        
        require_once("connect.php");
        
        $query="INSERT INTO `Utenti`(`username`, `password`) VALUES('$username','$password')";
        
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
            $response['success']=true;
            $response['message']="Utente inserito correttamente";
        }else{
             $response['success']=false;
             $response['message']="Utente non inserito ";
        }
    }else{
         $response['success']=false;
         $response['message']="CONNESSIONE NON RIUSCITA ";
    }
    
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing "connesso" in your server response. Remove this in your save.php file.

Update your query in save.php with this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO `Utenti`(`username`, `password`) VALUES('".$username."','".$password')."');";
```

Comment: Thanks, now I dont get error anymore but still dont inserting nothing in database

Comment: @TommyCisternino Android code is fine, Please test your PHP code. can you share the PHP code in your question? there can be some issue.

Comment: added in the original post

Comment: Nothing to do. With your query gives me back the principal error.

Comment: modified the query like this:
        $query="INSERT INTO `Utenti`(`username`, `password`) VALUES('".$username."','".$password."');";

no error anymore but still does not inserting nothing

Comment: doing some test I get that the problem is in the save.php where is the if(query)

Comment: Anyway i posted an other question, if you can help me again i will be gratefull to u